Cheap personal mobile phone number to receive text
I'm looking for a service that provides me with a cheap personal mobile phone number to receive text messages (mainly verification codes). Sending text messages I would consider optional. Voice messaging (phone calls) aren't required.
I'd expect such a service to be very cheap (a few bucks a year) and they should provide me with a phone number that doesn't change and is mine only.
I am aware that there are free services out there providing access to shared phone numbers. I can see all sorts of messages (mainly verification codes) people have requested. And everybody can read the messages intended for me. The phone numbers provided by these services often change. This is not what I'm looking for.
I want a cheap alternative to a personal mobile phone number, that is private and I want to retain my number.
I don't care about the country of the phone number.

Did you consider having a "prepaid" card? It usually has an initial fee, but no service costs on reception, at least in Switzerland. Or is there a reason not to use this?

I had such a prepaid card cancelled on me for "not using it". Found out about it month later, when I investigated why the phone I used for it had no reception. Took me another few month to get the company to confirm that it was cancelled. Apparently, they had a clause that requieres me to send a text or make a phone call at least once a year in order to keep my number. I would like a service without such shenanigans, preferably over the internet, not on a mobile network.

Yes, happens to me once in a while. I guess it's because a mobile phone number is a scarce resource and they don't want to waste them for no business. For me, it's acceptable in return for my use case. Plus, they send a "warning" message beforehand, remembering me to send a message to avoid termination.
